# DoesNotExist: Customer matching query does not exist (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Inside my Django app I've received a "DoesNotExist: Customer matching query does not exist" wherein the stack trace points out that when attempting to query information from a group's Customer (a Customer can have many groups) the linked resource "does not exist" yet the customer does indeed exist in the database (and has the information requested):

```
 class Group(models.Model):
      id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
      customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, to_field="customer_id", related_name='groups', null=True, blank=True) ## a blank customer_id indicates the group is 'private'
      ...

     @property
     def groups_linked(self):

        if self.is_private:
             linked = False
        else:
             linked = Customer.objects.value_list('cross-group-collaboration', flat=True).get(pk=self.customer_id) ## here the error bubbles up saying the Customer does not exist!

        if linked:
              return {'customer_id' : self.customer_id }
         else:
              return group = { 'group_id' : self.if}
```

From the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets) the description of this error is as follows: "Note that there is a difference between using get(), and using filter() with a slice of [0]. If there are no results that match the query, get() will raise a DoesNotExist exception. This exception is an attribute of the model class that the query is being performed on - so in the code above, if there is no Entry object with a primary key of 1, Django will raise Entry.DoesNotExist."

If the information does indeed exist but the error above is being triggered, what could cause this?

Comment: In your shell or in the code itself, just run `Customer.objects.value_list('private', flat=True).count()`  - My guess is, the count is 0. Also, `.get()` would work for `filter` only if there is 1 element. If there are > 1, it would result in `MultipleObjectsReturned ` exception

Comment: No, there is a returning count. And yes, when I explore and run a SQL command ```SELECT 'customer'.'cross-group-collab' FROM 'customer' WHERE 'customer'.customer_id = <customer number>;``` there is only **one** match. As the relationship is one sided, a Customer can have many groups but groups can ONLY belong to one Customer, there is no potential of multiple Customers being returned for a given group.

Comment: is that 'cross-group-collaboration' or 'cross-group-collab' ?

Comment: Also, you can directly access related (foreign key) model instances using (in this case) `self.customer`

Comment: My bad - it's cross-group-collaboration.

Comment: And again, the foreign key is the customer_id --  customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, to_field="customer_id", related_name='groups', null=True, blank=True) -- so accessing the customer is through the ID

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here but in any case there is no need to go looking for the Customer object as you already have it as self.customer

How about something like:

```
@property
def groups_linked(self):
    if self.customer is not None:
        return {'customer_id': self.customer.id}
    else:
        return {'group_id': self.id}
```

Comment: The customer_id is the foreign key linking my groups and customers tables. Since groups can be private, there is no need to check if groups can have cross-group-collab (basically they can work with other groups the customer has).

Comment: @Robin: you can even make it simpler by just testing `self.customer_id`, and it will avoid a useless query.

Comment: The groups_linked will be **false** if the group is private, that is it's a private group. Customer's are account holders and there are also account logins as well, all associated with a customer, but accounts can have private groups. The issue here is a group, that is not private, and has the ability to do "cross-group-collaboration" (e.g. share info with other groups in the Customer list of public groups), is not being found on the .get() query (but in the DB a customer id is linked to the group & is "true" for cross-group-collab).

Comment: @LorenaNicole as you haven't shown your whole class I'm unsure as to where self.is_private is defined but it seems to be it is when the customer is not set so could be factored out. It looks to me that the root of the problem is that is_private is False but the customer is not set. If you want to confirm in SQL you should look at the group table not the customer table I think.